# Having an issue trying to get the telegram chat ID

Tags: python, api, telegram

I am trying to get the chat ID by typing the following request : `https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOTAPY}/getUpdates` but I am getting this error :

`{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: can't use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first"}`

It seems I will have to change something in telegram python code, does anyone of you have any idea how I can resolve this issue ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You no need to change anything in the code itself.

There are two mutually exclusive ways of receiving updates for your bot — the **getUpdates** method on one hand and **Webhooks** on the other.

You will not be able to receive updates using `getUpdates` for as long as an outgoing webhook is set up.

Use `deleteWebhook` method to remove webhook integration if you decide to switch back to getUpdates.

You can find detailed instructions how to do it on official [Telegram Bot API site](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates).